# Где можно скачать Android Studio, но меньше по объëму памяти?

Tags: java, android, ide, apk, app

Мне очень нужен Android Studio, но он занимает слишком много места. Существует ли более лëгкая версия Android Studio? Или есть аналоги этой среды разработки?

Comment: https://ru.wikihow.com/%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-Eclipse-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD-ADT

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) с [андроид плагином](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adelphes.android-dev-ext), собирать можно через терминал при помощи gradle.

[Туториал](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/building-android-apps-using-microsofts-vs-code-instead-saamer-mansoor/) как это все вместе подружить.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это подойдёт. VS Code места занимает мало и мне эта IDE очень нравится.

Answer (score 0):

На оба вопроса ответ - нет. Однако можно писать код вообще без IDE, просто в текстовом редакторе набирая код. Потом файлы с кодом надо поместить в определённом порядке и с помощью консольного gradle собрать APK. Вообще, чтобы комфортно кодить нужен довольно мощный комп (чтобы IDE нормально работала).

Comment: Спасибо! А Вы не знаете сколько Android Studio занимает гб? И как в ней создать apk?

Comment: Сложно сказать. На винде у меня сама студия - 1.5 гига. Но ещё AndroidSdk папка есть. В ней много всего, не всё нужно, но она 33 гига занимает.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Характеристики моего древнего ноута, при этом работаю в android studio
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот основная информация по [android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio?gclid=CjwKCAjwoP6LBhBlEiwAvCcthPWuA_LA3B_fF2-xQxymo2zBJyDsn1iejermpRD_M2XzWixCLhx8txoCTeUQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Изучить для примера можно по книге [Head First. Программирование для Android](https://ru.pdfdrive.com/head-first-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-android-e176038850.html) по полочкам всё разложено!

Из аналогов **xamarin studio**!

Comment: Спасибо! А где я могу скачать Xamarin Studio? Когда перехожу на xamarin.com меня перекидывает на страницу Microsoft, а там нужна Visual Studio.

Comment: В Visual Studio тоже можно создавать приложения под андроид. Но сразу скажу лучше не морочить себе голову и использовать android studio